# Problemas ao declarar uma chave estrangeira utilizando hibernate

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsf, hibernate, chave-estrangeira

Ola.Preciso de ajuda para declarar uma chave de estrangeira utilizando hibernate em um projeto com JSF, consultei vários sites e apostilas e não encontrei uma solução. Onde tenho as classes já mapeadas calendário e datas, onde um calendário contêm várias datas e datas contêm um calendário.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

Classe calendario

```
@Id
@Column(name = "calendario_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int calendario_id;

@Column(name = "ano")
private int ano;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "calendarioDatas")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Datas> datasCalendario = new ArrayList<>();
```

Classe datas

```
@Id
@Column(name = "data_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int data_id;

@Column(name = "tipo_data")
private String tipo_data;

@Column(name = "data")
private Date data;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="calendarioDatas", nullable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "calendarioDatas_fk")
private Calendario calendarioDatas = new Calendario();
```

Classe onde tem o metodo de cadastrar as datas apos serem selecionadas

```
public void commitBancoDeDados(){
   hibernateUtil.cadastrar(calendario); 
   hibernateUtil.atualizar(datas);
}
```

O hibernateUtil.cadastrar faz a persistencia da classe calendario, já o hibernateUtil.atualizar faz o merge da classe datas.

Comment: No contexto dos banco de dados, o conceito de chave estrangeira se refere ao tipo de relacionamento entre as tabelas, isso você já mapeou com '@ManyToOne' e '@OneToMany'. Não entendi a sua questão.

Comment: Certo. Mas na hora de cadastrar o calendário não apresenta a relação entre as duas entidades. Pois cadastro as datas e cada data cadastrada deveria receber o id do calendário.

Comment: Conferi no script do banco de dados e também não apresenta a relação entre as entidades

Comment: Você pode postar as entidades Data e Calendario no Banco e o método em que você salva a entidade data ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, colocando o método que usei para enviar as datas para o banco

Comment: Bom, em algum momento desse fluxo, você seta o calendario dentro de data?

Comment: o que é datas ? um list<Data> ou um objeto Data ?

Comment: Não seto o calendário em nenhum momento, Datas é a classe onde são armazenados as datas selecionadas pelo usuários.

Comment: Então, imagine que eu estou com um calendário de id = 1 salvo no banco de dados, quando eu salvar uma nova data preciso informar qual o calendario que ela se relaciona, dessa forma, antes de salvar ou atualizar a entidade data eu preciso fazer : data.setCalendarioDatas (calendario);
dessa forma o hibernate irá colocar irá colocar o ID de calendário na FK que você criou.

Comment: Facilita bastante se você postar como ta entidade no banco

Comment: Declarando a chave estrangeira, não deveria inserir automaticamente o ID ?

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com Declarando, mas o java não associa automaticamente que a data X irá se relacionar com o calendario Y, isso não acontece à menos que você fale explicitamente que um objeto está relacionado com o outro.

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer essa relação?

Comment: postei na resposta, olha se te ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz esse exemplo mostrando como você deve fazer para associar as entidades em questão.

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendario calendario = new Calendario();
        calendario.setId(1L);

        Datas datas = new Datas();
        datas.setId(1L);

        // método que salva o calendario
        // hibernateUtil.cadastrar(calendario);

        // depois do calendario esta salvo , você relaciona a data a ele.
        datas.setCalendario(calendario);

         // método que salva a data.
        // hibernateUtil.cadastrar(data);

    }

}

class Calendario {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Datas {
    private Long id;

    private Calendario calendario;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Calendario getCalendario() {
        return calendario;
    }

    public void setCalendario(Calendario calendario) {
        this.calendario = calendario;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, logo modifico meu código e faço os testes, mas agradeço pela sua ajuda novamente.